# Mac Show All Windows for an app in dock Sierra

Tags: mac, macos, dock, expose

When I had El Capitan, I was able to (or assigned a shortcut to) : when I hovered over a dock icon and scrolled up (with mouse or trackpad), it would show all windows of the dock application i hovered over.  i can't remember now that i have sierra how i did this ; any ideas?

Comment: i wonder if this command used to do it, and maybe from el capitan to sierra it no longer works.. :
defaults write com.apple.dock scroll-to-open -bool TRUE;killall Dock

Answer (score 2):

Go with the the mouse pointer to the dock icon in question, then with three fingers go up, this will reveal all open windows of this application.

Comment: this works and isn't bad if you're using trackpad, but not great if you're using a mouse

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the dock icon, and select `Show All Windows`, or hover over the dock icon and use three finger swipe **down** (or four if it doesn't work).

Alternatively, you can go into it with three finger swipe down (again, try four if it doesn't work) in any app, and then click on the app icon.

Comment: This will not show windows that are full screen.

Answer (score 0):

well this guy jon hitchcock solved it in apple forum....
it was tinkertool that has this option
https://discussions.apple.com/message/31284014#31284014